# Can i use click to make two animations? (svg animation)

Tags: svg

I'm a newbie of svg animation and know nothing about code languages. Furthermore, i'm sure my question is as silly as it could be, but here i go anyway: I have a circle on a bar, and i'd want that circle to move from left to right on the bar when i click and then to move it back to its original position with another click. Is this something i can do? I succeeded in doing the first animation using SMIL (animate) but i can't seem to get the second animation right. I'm providing my Html code (I use Inkscape, btw).
Thanks for any kind answer!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="1052.3622"
   height="744.09448"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.5 r10040"
   sodipodi:docname="switch.svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="2.8"
     inkscape:cx="220.45194"
     inkscape:cy="418.19862"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="true"
     units="mm"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="705"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1">
    <inkscape:grid
       snapvisiblegridlinesonly="true"
       enabled="true"
       visible="true"
       empspacing="5"
       id="grid3050"
       type="xygrid" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <script
     type="text/javascript"
     id="inkwebjs">
</script>
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     transform="translate(0,-308.2677)"
     id="layer1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     inkscape:label="Layer 1">
    <path
       sodipodi:nodetypes="csccscc"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       id="bar"
       d="m 265,309.09448 c 0,0 -15,0 -15,15 0,15 15,15 15,15 l 65,0 c 0,0 15,0 15,-15 0,-15 -15,-15 -15,-15 z"
       style="fill:#999999;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.06299213;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
       transform="translate(0,308.2677)" />
    <path
       transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,46,373.08659)"
       d="m 280,324.09448 c 0,13.80712 -11.19288,25 -25,25 -13.80712,0 -25,-11.19288 -25,-25 0,-13.80712 11.19288,-25 25,-25 13.80712,0 25,11.19288 25,25 z"
       sodipodi:ry="25"
       sodipodi:rx="25"
       sodipodi:cy="324.09448"
       sodipodi:cx="255"
       id="switch"
       style="fill:#999999;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.32874016;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0"
       sodipodi:type="arc" />
  </g>
 <animate
  id="switch_anim"
  to="m 380,324.09448 c 0,13.80712 -11.19288,25 -25,25 -13.80712,0 -25,-11.19288 -25,-25 0,-13.80712 11.19288,-25 25,-25 13.80712,0 25,11.19288 25,25 z"
  from="m 280,324.09448 c 0,13.80712 -11.19288,25 -25,25 -13.80712,0 -25,-11.19288 -25,-25 0,-13.80712 11.19288,-25 25,-25 13.80712,0 25,11.19288 25,25 z"
  dur="0.3s"
  begin="click"
  end="reverse_switch_anim.begin"
  attributeName="d"
  fill="freeze"  
  xlink:href="#switch"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you cheat, have two (or more) objects and switch between them. If they look the same nobody will ever know they aren't actually the same object.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="1052.3622"
   height="744.09448">
  <g
     transform="translate(0,-308.2677)"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       id="bar"
       d="m 265,309.09448 c 0,0 -15,0 -15,15 0,15 15,15 15,15 l 65,0 c 0,0 15,0 15,-15 0,-15 -15,-15 -15,-15 z"
       style="fill:#999999;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.06299213;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
       transform="translate(0,308.2677)" />
    <path
       transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,46,373.08659)"
       d="m 280,324.09448 c 0,13.80712 -11.19288,25 -25,25 -13.80712,0 -25,-11.19288 -25,-25 0,-13.80712 11.19288,-25 25,-25 13.80712,0 25,11.19288 25,25 z"
       id="switch"
       style="fill:#999999;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.32874016;" />
    <path
       transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,46,373.08659)"
       d="m 380,324.09448 c 0,13.80712 -11.19288,25 -25,25 -13.80712,0 -25,-11.19288 -25,-25 0,-13.80712 11.19288,-25 25,-25 13.80712,0 25,11.19288 25,25 z"
       id="switch2"
       style="fill:#999999;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.32874016;display:none;" />
  </g>
 <animate
  id="switch_anim"
  to="m 380,324.09448 c 0,13.80712 -11.19288,25 -25,25 -13.80712,0 -25,-11.19288 -25,-25 0,-13.80712 11.19288,-25 25,-25 13.80712,0 25,11.19288 25,25 z"
  from="m 280,324.09448 c 0,13.80712 -11.19288,25 -25,25 -13.80712,0 -25,-11.19288 -25,-25 0,-13.80712 11.19288,-25 25,-25 13.80712,0 25,11.19288 25,25 z"
  dur="0.3s"
  begin="click"
  attributeName="d"
  fill="remove"  
  xlink:href="#switch"/>
 <set
  begin="switch_anim.end"
  attributeName="display"
        to="none"
  fill="freeze"  
  xlink:href="#switch"/>
 <set
  begin="switch_anim.end"
  attributeName="display"
        to="block"
  fill="freeze"  
  xlink:href="#switch2"/>
 <animate
  id="switch2_anim"
  from="m 380,324.09448 c 0,13.80712 -11.19288,25 -25,25 -13.80712,0 -25,-11.19288 -25,-25 0,-13.80712 11.19288,-25 25,-25 13.80712,0 25,11.19288 25,25 z"
  to="m 280,324.09448 c 0,13.80712 -11.19288,25 -25,25 -13.80712,0 -25,-11.19288 -25,-25 0,-13.80712 11.19288,-25 25,-25 13.80712,0 25,11.19288 25,25 z"
  dur="0.3s"
  begin="click"
  attributeName="d"
  fill="remove"  
  xlink:href="#switch2"/>
 <set
  begin="switch2_anim.end"
  attributeName="display"
        to="none"
  fill="freeze"  
  xlink:href="#switch2"/>
 <set
  begin="switch2_anim.end"
  attributeName="display"
        to="block"
  fill="freeze"  
  xlink:href="#switch"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Robert! That's exactly what i needed! I noticed that i can run the animation you made the first time correctly, but then my browser (Chrome) fails to do it any other time. Do you know why does this happen? Can i have it repeat the animation any time i click on it correctly?

Comment: Firefox works so I assume that's a Chrome bug. You could try reporting it to [their bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: Again thank you very much Robert. I reported it. I hope somebody can find a solution to it.